# Is it possible to minimize objects definition as well(collapse code for objects) (Specifically Dart with flutter)(Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a long code for example like this.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('building');
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => changeThemeAfterBuild(context));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            _logEntryDetailBloc.dispose();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text(this.widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: new Material(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'Message:',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(127, 127, 127, 1)),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      widget.logEntry.message,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    StreamBuilder(
                        stream: _logEntryDetailBloc.logEntryDetailStream,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          print("has detail data ${snapshot.hasData}");
                          print(snapshot.data);
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            var logEntry = (snapshot.data as LogEntry);
                            if (logEntry.logLevel.name == ERROR)
                              return Container(
                                child: ErrorDetailScreenContainer(),
                                height:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 156,
                              );

                            return Container(
                                child: Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
                                height:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200);
                          } else {
                            return new Image(
                                image: new AssetImage("images/loader.gif"));
                          }
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now the problem is since I am doing flutter the objects are nested and each object being child of some other object.
and thus when the Parent object becomes large by nesting. it becomes slightly unreadable and bracket matching becomes tough

Solution What I am looking is something like:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('building');
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => changeThemeAfterBuild(context));

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...), // I folded here
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: new Material(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
                child: Column(...)  // I foldere here too
              )
            ),
           ),
         ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Is Something like this possible.
Or any other alternative that I can perform, so that it looks cleaner.

Comment: Are you asking for some capability in your editor to fold code? That's going to be highly dependent on the editor you are using - can you add that detail to your question? Both intelliJ and vscode should support folding.

Comment: Edited the post. Folding is there but on class definitions and function definition , comments etc but not on object declaration/definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flutter AndroidStudio/IntelliJ plugin supports this today. Here is a screenshot showing your build method collapsing a couple of subtrees. Notice that the widget ui guides also make it easier to keep track of a big widget tree in Intellij. [image: Screenshot showing collapsing a block]

Comment: Updating the android studio worked for me. I was using older version which does not enable this. Thanks for the help